# How to select and delete the border in an EPS file in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, selections, eps

I have a graphic [CS5 eps here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By4WA9GK6t9DUk0wd1Y3LUV5X0U/edit?usp=sharing) that draws a honeycomb lattice. But I have a problem: When I selected it, I found that there is a border around it as shown in [image]

But I only want the honeycomb lattice part. I tried lasso tool in adobe illustrator to select the honeycomb, but it turns out I can't get rid of the border being selected.

**So How can I select the honeycomb without the border?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .eps file is a vector file and not a "ps graphic".

You can see the vector construction in the wireframe (within Illustrator):

[image]

You'll need a vector editing application to effectively remove the extra lines and anchors.

You can try using [**Inkscape**](http://www.inkscape.org/en/) to open the EPS and remove the extra objects but you won't be able to effectively remove anything with Photoshop alone. At least not if you wish to keep the file as a vector Smart Object within Photoshop.

Note: That particular eps was generated by Illustrator CC and it would appear that only Illustrator CC will open it. I'm unable to open the EPS with any older version of Illustrator. Therefore, Inkscape may also have a problem opening *that* eps file.

Comment: As far as I know Inkscape won't open EPS files out of the box; I think some sort of conversion would be required before opening it or perhaps there's a plugin available

Comment: That's possible. I have Illustrator so I don't really use Inkscape. I suggested Inkscape because it's free. I was under the impression eps was generally not an issue with Inkscape. But.. that is an Illustrator CC eps so it's a *very* cutting edge EPS format as opposed to an older version of an eps.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't able to open it in AI CS5 so I tried Inkscape with no luck either. With some googling around it appears it's possible with some workarounds, but certainly not worth the effort for me right now :)

Comment: @Scott Thank you, Scott! Wireframe view is quite useful! I get a clean honeycomb lattice now.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your `Layers`. Click on the little circle next to each layer to highlight that specific layer and see which one it is.

Looking at your file, it is immediately obvious that it is the top layer:

[image]

To select individual points you can use the `Direct Selection Tool`.[image]. Just click on it, and then click and drag from anywhere on your artboard to select all points within your selection.

#### To Select and Delete the border..

1. Use the `Direct Selection Tool`.
2. Click any unoccupied space on the artboard to deselect anything that might be selected.
3. Select each anchor point of the border individually ***or*** click on the circle next to the top layer (of the third layer group) in the `Layers` panel.
4. Press <kbd>Delete</kbd>

It will reveal the following image, I'm not going to investigate further to find out why.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I opened it in Photoshop and there was no border nor background.  It looks like you're using Illustrator.  Illustrator CS5, what I use, won't open the file, says it was created by a newer version, so I can't check, but what you might try is either the Object>Expand--if it is a vector image--and then ungroup the object; or you could do a live trace and ungroup if it isn't actually vector--that works for simple images like this one.